# Is iterating over self a bad practice?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.data = dictionary

    def __iter__(self):
        for key,val in self.data.items():
            yield (key, val)

    def iter_on_self(self):
        for i in self:
            yield i
```

I understand that `iter_on_self` above is redundant, but I wanted to know if `for i in self: #do something` is considered a bad practice. If it is a bad practice and I have a need loop over self from another method in the same class, then how would I implement that.

Comment: The loop in `__iter__` will raise `ValueError: Not enough arguments to unpack`. Looping over `self.data` will give you just the keys unless you say `for k, v in self.data.items()`

Comment: My bad, I meant `for key,val in self.data.items()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Why would it be? The reason you define `__iter__` is so that you can iterate over your object. I'd argue that it's bad practice to reimplement it when it's already there.

Here's an example of the behavior you describe being used in a [standard library python object](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py) (`OrderedDict`).

```
def __reduce__(self):
    'Return state information for pickling'
    items = [[k, self[k]] for k in self]
    tmp = self.__map, self.__root
    del self.__map, self.__root
    inst_dict = vars(self).copy()
    self.__map, self.__root = tmp
    if inst_dict:
        return (self.__class__, (items,), inst_dict)
    return self.__class__, (items,)
```